# Downloading using JavaScript not working TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript

I wrote this file. The only function that is not working is the download function. Im trying to fix it but I'm running out of idea's

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    'use strict';
    function Download(ele) {
        let Video_Title = document.getElementsByClassName("page-title");
        let Video_URL = document.getElementsByClassName("text-center download-ready");
        let High = Video_URL[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

        var arg = { url: High[0].href,
                   name: Video_Title[0].firstChild
                  };
        GM_download(arg);
    }
    function addDownloadbtn(ele) {
        let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.innerHTML = "DOWNLOAD";
        btn.onclick = () => {
            Download(ele);
        }

        ele.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), ele.childNodes[0]);
        ele.insertBefore(btn, ele.childNodes[0]);

    }
    let Video_Title = document.getElementsByClassName("page-title");
    // V = Video_Title[0]
    console.log(Video_Title);

    for (let Title of Video_Title) {
        addDownloadbtn(Title);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please expand on what "not working" means. Are there any error messages? What happens that's not supposed to? What doesn't happen that **is** supposed to?

Comment: No, that's the reason why I'm confused.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log(arg)` above your `GM_download` call, to check the data is valid? E.g. the documentation for it says: "the file extension needs to be whitelisted at Tampermonkey's options page", which may be one issue.

Comment: I try it. Still nothing.